# Let $n$ be an even number. How many $n$ fair coin flip sequences have the number of heads greater than or equal to the number of tails.

Tags: probability

See title.

Also if take our sample space to be sequences of any length. What is the probability of getting a sequence with the number heads greater than or equal the number tails?

These are all with fair coins, but also using $p$ and $1-p$ for a biased coin could also be interesting.

Comment: For a fair coin work out the proportion of sequences where there is equality.  By symmetry, half the rest will have more heads than tails and the other half of the rest more tails than heads.

Comment: The probability of heads does not impact the number of sequences, just the probability of a particular sequence.  The title does not match the body of the question.  Please clarify your question.  What do you know of the binomial distribution?  What have you tried?

Comment: I would agree with the symmetry argument in the odd case, but doesn't $n$ being even change the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about the expectation of such a number (otherwise any number is *possible*).
The expectation should be $pN$.